# How to make element fill the remaining space inside a Row or a Column in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-layout

I am trying to show two text messages besides each other in a row but when the size of the first text is big, the second view gets pushed out of the screen as shown below: 
The code:

```kotlin
Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    Text(
        text = "safasfasdfsasdssdsaasdsadsdsaasdsasdsasdasddassdsssdasdadsasdasdsd",
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 12.dp, bottom = 12.dp, end = 12.dp, start = 10.dp)
            .background(Color.Gray)
    )
    Text(
        text = "12:00 am",
        style = messageTimeTextStyle,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
        maxLines = 1
    )
}
```

The output:
[image]

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can apply the **`weight`** modifier **only** to the long text.

The `.weight` modifier sizes the element's width proportional to its weight relative to other weighted sibling elements in the `Row`. The parent will divide the horizontal space remaining **after measuring unweighted child elements** and distribute it according to this weight

Something like:

```
Row() {
    Text(text = "safasfasdfsasdssdsaasdsadsdsaasdsasdsasdasddassdsssdasdadsasdasdsd",
        Modifier
            .padding(top = 12.dp, bottom = 12.dp, end = 12.dp, start = 10.dp)
            .background(Color.Gray)
            .weight(1f)
         )
    Text(
        text = "12:00 am",
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
        maxLines = 1
    )
}
```

[image]

or

```
Row() {
    Column(Modifier.weight(1f)){
        Text(text = "safasfasdfsasdssdsaasdsadsdsa.." , ....)
    }
    Column() {
        Text( text = "12.00 ..", .....)
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if my longer text disappears at runtime? I still want the second text to remain at the end. Is that possible?

Comment: @SarahKhan I believe the second text will remain at the end as the Modifier.weight(1f) is applied to the Column and not the Text composable itself

Answer (score 1):

If you wrap your text in boxes and give your boxes weight, then you get what you are looking for:

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Box(Modifier.weight(2f)) {
            Text(
                text = "safasfasdfsasdssdsaasdsafasfasdfsasdssdsaasdsafasfasdfsasdssdsaasd",
                Modifier
                    .padding(top = 12.dp, bottom = 12.dp, end = 12.dp, start = 10.dp)
                    .background(Color.Gray)
            )
        }
        Box(Modifier.weight(1f)) {
            Text(
                text = "12:00 am",
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(horizontal = 16.dp),
                maxLines = 1
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes I can absolutely do that but I want the first text to take all the available space and leave only space for the second view, just as expected from a normal Linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

If you assign weight only to the Text, it will take all the space available and it will leave just enough space that is needed for the Box. I am copying and editing the same code from the reply above by @Code Poet.

```
    Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
        Box(Modifier.weight(2f)) {
            Text(
                text = "safasfasdfsasdssdsaasdsafasfasdfsasdssdsaasdsafasfasdfsasdssdsaasd",
                Modifier
                    .padding(top = 12.dp, bottom = 12.dp, end = 12.dp, start = 10.dp)
                    .background(Color.Gray)
            )
        }
        Box {
            Text(
                text = "12:00 am",
                maxLines = 1
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Preview:
[image]