# Android sticky - footer using jetpack compose: Align footer view to table, until it reaches screen size and then become fixed at the bottom

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, sticky-footer, android-compose-lazyfor

I want to achieve this using jetpack compose.

[image]

**A** is scrollable list of row items. When **A** is smaller than screen(or parent) size, **B**(footer) should be placed bellow the last row. When **A** + **B** are bigger than screen size, then **B** becomes fixed at the bottom and **A** content is scrollable. I'm wondering if there is easy way to achieve this, using compose ConstraintLayout.

Answer (score 18):

The solution is to use `Modifier.weight(1f, false)` in A. This is because the parent element's size will first be used by unweighted elements and then the remaining space will be distributed to weighted elements according to their weights. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66622843/7089239) for more details.

Answer (score 10):

There are many ways to do this but the most efficient way is to use the `bottomBar` property of `Scaffold` View.

For example:

```
@Composable
fun RenderContent() {
    Scaffold(
        topBar = { /* Your app bar goes here */ },
        bottomBar = { /* Anything you place in here will be stick to the bottom. */ }
    ) {
        // ... Rest of the content
        // Benefits: If you make the content scrollable and
        // the `bottomBar` composable remain on top of the content
    }
}
```

Comment: good option. save my time. any idea to redusee bottom bar unwanted padding?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you are trying to add a footer view to a LazyColmn. The LazyColumn in JetpackCompose is behaving like the native ListView. I will give an example of a LazyColumn that has a view(composable) at the bottom that is shown when you scroll at the end of the list:

```
LazyColumn() {
item {
    //If you want the first item to stay always on top as you scroll use stickyHeader for this section.
    Text("This is the first item")
}
items(listItems.size) {
    Text("This is a normal list item")
}
item {
    Text("This item will behave as a footer and display at the end of the list")
}
```

}

Hope this helps somebody.
Thanks

Comment: This will not behave as a sticky footer. This will just show as the last item on the list.

Comment: Hi Worker123 this solution is wrong can you delete it?

Answer (score 0):

While most straight forward way would be the use of `ConstraintLayout` **I can't recommend it**, since there are currently too many bugs and it doesn't seem stable from my experience.

The simplest way outside of ConstraintLayout is using a any container element that draws children over eachother, such as `Scaffold` or `Box`. Since **`Scaffold` holds too much logic for such a simple workaround**, I'd go with `Box` every single time.

The simples example I can give is

```
Box {
    LazyColumn {
        stickyHeader {

        }
        items(listOf()) {
            
        }
    }

    // doesn't have to be a Box, any element will do, such as Row/Column/...
    // the Alignment.BottomCenter is the key
    Box(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter)) {
        //This is your sticky footer Content
    }
}
```

The only drawback I see is offset you have to provide to the `LazyColumn` in order to be "above" the footer. This can be achieved like this:

```
Box {
    LazyColumn {
        stickyHeader {

        }
        items(listOf()) {

        }
        item {
            Spacer(
                modifier = Modifier.height(
                    with(LocalDensity.current) {
                        stickyFooterHeight.intValue.toDp()
                    }
                )
            )
        }
    }

    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .align(Alignment.BottomCenter)
            .onSizeChanged {
                stickyFooterHeight.intValue = it.height
            }
    ) {
        //...
    }
}
```

Optionally, you can turn it into a component, which you can easily reuse again and add `.animateContentSize` on the `Spacer` to make it look seamless.