# Animate view position change depending on another view's visibility in Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Let's say I have a `TextField` and an image view above it. I hide the image on click and `TextField` expands vertically. I want to animate that expansion (slide-up animation is preferred), how can I do that?

```
Column(horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
    ImageView()
    ...
    InputView(
        onClick { onEventReceived(Contract.InputViewClick) }
    )
}
```

InputView implementation:

```
@Composable
InputView(
    onClick: () -> Unit
) {
    ConstraintLayout(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {
        // other views are also hidden on click
        val (inputArea, otherView1, otherView2) = createRefs()

        TextField(
            value = ...,
            onValueChange = { ... },
            colors = textFieldColors,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .constrainAs(inputArea) {
                    centerHorizontallyTo(parent)
                },
            interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
                .also { source ->
                    LaunchedEffect(source) {
                        source.interactions.collect {
                            when(it) {
                                is PressInteraction.Release -> onClick()
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        
            // some other views
            ...
        }
    )
}
```

I am not very experienced with animation in Compose, I am not sure that `AnimatedVisibility` is the thing that I want to use in such case

Comment: After re-reading your question, I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Should the height of the TextField expand or should the size remain the same, and the TextField just should shift upwards?

Comment: @BenjyTec sorry for confusing you, I meant the height expansion

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think the `weight` modifier could do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [AnimatedVisibility](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/animation/composables-modifiers#animatedvisibility) is the way to go. In order to make the InputView expand as soon as the ImageView disappears, please try out the `weight` modifier:

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable() {

    var showImage by rememberSaveable{ mutableStateOf(true) }

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        AnimatedVisibility(
            visible = showImage
        ) {
            ImageView(
                onClick = { showImage = false }
            ) 
        }
        // ...
        InputView(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f),
            onClick = { onEventReceived(Contract.InputViewClick) }
        )
    }
}
```

Then remove all the `modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()` declarations in your InputView, as they probably will push the other Composables off the screen.

The InputView should then fill up the remaining space in the Column. Please note that the `Column` will probably need to have a fixed size, either by setting an absolute value or by filling the screen height.

Comment: Well this indeed animates the input view expansion, but I am not sure how the weight modifier should work. For some reason it fills up the whole screen, so the views between the `ImageView` and `InputView` become invisible. Before `AnimatedVisibility` there were no animation, but the input view did not fill up the whole screen

Comment: And column has `fillMaxHeight` modifier

Comment: The `weight` modifier allows for a relative width or height definition. If you set `weight` to only one children, it should fill up the entire remaining space, but without removing anything else. See also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66622843/8331157

Comment: My guess is that `modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()` in the InputView causes the other elements to be pushed off screen. So please try to remove the two usages, and let me know if that changes anything.

Comment: Removing this modifiers did not change the behavior. My guess is that animation forces excessive expansion. When I trigger the event by pushing the special button which is not the part of input view - animation and expansion works correctly. Before using `AnimatedVisibility` the expansion was also correct

Comment: I am sorry, you were right. I should have used weight modifier and remove 'fillMaxHeight' from Constraint composable. Now it works like charm! Thanks man

Comment: Happy to hear that it finally worked, you're welcome!

Comment: Well, it still does not work as expected ( For some reason I have mistaken the behavior for the correct one. However your idea with `AnimatedVisibility` is correct, so my current problem will be the topic for another question :)